# Why need triangle arrays in central limit theorem?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

There seems to be two versions of CLT, one using triangle arrays (version 1),  and the other not (version 2). Does Version 2 imply Version 1? If it does, what would be the point of using the concept of triangle arrays?

Comment: If version 2 refers to a version concerning i.i.d. random variables, then version 1 is contained in version 2 since an i.i.d. sequence is in particular a triangular array.